# angular ui tree for complex json

Tags: angularjs

How to create angular ui tree for complex json?

```
[
  {
    "name": "bmw",
    "model": "x3",
    "specs": [
      {
        "name": "bmw",
        "maxspeed": 350,
        "minspeed": 0,
        "model": "x3",
        "type": "car"
      },
      {
        "value": 30,
        "name": "bmw",
        "maxspeed": 350,
        "minspeed": 0,
        "model": "x3",
        "type": "car"
      }
    ],
    "available": true,
    "price": 50
  },
  {
    "name": "audi",
    "model": "r8",
    "specs": [
      {
        "color": [
          {
            "value": "red",
            "price": 100
          },
          {
            "value": [
              "white",
              "black"
            ],
            "price": 200
          }
        ],
        "maxspeed": 330,
        "minspeed": 0,
        "type": "car"
      },
      {
        "color": [
          {
            "value": "blue",
            "price": 300
          },
          {
            "value": [
              "yellow",
              "gold"
            ],
            "price": 500
          }
        ],
        "maxspeed": 330,
        "minspeed": 0,
        "type": "car"
      }
    ],
    "available": true
  }
]
```

Comment: Try constructing the tree with the help of basic example given in the documentation here  'https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree' and update here if you are stuck somewhere such that we could try fixing it.

Comment: i have created plunker for angular ui tree of my code.i am unable to understand how to iterate on json data to create nodes so that i can drag and delete single node.please take a look at https://plnkr.co/edit/AREJ2oId98NwCm8EOVyo?p=preview